# AWS - DynamoDB - how to get object that have only one field from DataBase

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DynamoDB, I have table called "cache" with only one field that is String - "apiToken", how can I get this String from DB when I have only that one field? Is this even possible?

```
    private String getAuthToken() {
    // TODO: Replace with cache fetched from DB instead of refreshApiToken method

    Cache cache = new Cache();
    cache.setApiToken(this.refreshApiToken());

    return cache.getApiToken();
}
```

Comment: You do not ever want to _get_ it, you can remove it or check wether or not it exists. But you should have set the table up to have `apiToken` as the primary partition key.

Comment: I've edited my question, now You see that I need to get it from DB to set it?

Comment: No, just delete the old entry and add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you only store one item in DynamoDB, I suggest to get rid of DynamoDB at all and use [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) instead.

If you want to stick to DynamoDB you can make a `ScanRequest` to get the first item.

```
ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
    .withTableName("cache")
    .withLimit(1);

ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
// handle result.getItems() ...
```